# How to fix Folder Path error in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, onedrive

I have this folder in my OneDrive and Just wondering how should I pass the path. Right now I'm getting "Folder not Found" when I try to do it like this.

[image]

```
$ServerRelativeUrl= "Documents/PC-OFFBOARD_USMPGWNCAT15C61-GZJY8T-01-Dec-0257/C$/'$Windows.~WS'"
```

Comment: PowerShell uses the backtick to escape special characters like `$`. Alternatively, don't use `""` for strings (where substitution is applied) but `''` (where it isn't), so `'Documents/PC-OFFBOARD_USMPGWNCAT15C61-GZJY8T-01-Dec-0257/C$/$Windows.~WS'` (note that you need the whole string in single quotes there, not part of it). Note that this folder appears to be "specially named" and may not be accessible through an API for other reasons, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With double-quoted `"` strings, you must escape characters with special meanings if you want them to be processed literally. PowerShell's escape character is the backtick `` ` ``. The dollar-symbol `$` must be prefixed with a backtick like this to be part of a literal file path:

```
"Documents/PC-OFFBOARD_USMPGWNCAT15C61-GZJY8T-01-Dec-0257/C`$/'`$Windows.~WS'"
```

Alternatively, you can use a single-quoted `'` string instead, making sure to escape the literal single-quotes with two single-quotes `''` (backticks won't escape in a literal string):

```
'Documents/PC-OFFBOARD_USMPGWNCAT15C61-GZJY8T-01-Dec-0257/C$/''$Windows.~WS'''
```

This loses your ability to insert *actual* intended variables though. You can however rely on the format operator in this case. To insert the literal string `'$Windows.~WS'` into the path, for example:

```
$folderName = '''$Windows.~WS'''
$fullPath = 'Documents/PC-OFFBOARD_USMPGWNCAT15C61-GZJY8T-01-Dec-0257/C$/{0}' -f $folderName
```